# How to connect/reboot to PC without monitor or remote access? Accidentally enabled X11 and can't undo it

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, intel, x11, reboot

I recently tried setting up an Intel NUC for remote access but it required a display to be connected -- I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (maybe 20.04, I can't check). So I installed the X11 dummy driver according to this: https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005081572-Display-issues-when-connecting-to-VNC-Server-running-on-Linux, but the NUC isn't attached to wifi/internet and I can't view via a monitor now to change it. How can I edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file or reset the settings?

Thanks... happy to share more information if needed

Comment: use a boot Media or use a physical adapter to get access. if its not possible, tell us why

Comment: Thanks! I just ended up buying a cheap dummy driver and it worked.  Eventually it would be nice to figure out how to do it without an adapter though...